# How to filter the select all checbox to select only specific Column on a grid

Tags: javascript, asp.net, checkbox

I have a Select All checkbox Java Script which is selecting only enabled checkboxes on my Gridview. 
the issue is I have added another checkbox column to my grid and the current Java Script is selecting all enabled checkboxes for all columns.

Here is my ASP.NET code:

```
        <asp:templatefield>
        <itemtemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRowPaid"  runat="server" Enabled='<%# IIf((Convert.ToString(Eval("Amount_Paid_By_Driver"))) = "1", "false", "true")%>' />
        </itemtemplate>
        <headertemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="SelectAllPaid" runat="server" onclick="CheckAllPaid(this);"   />
        </headertemplate>
        <headerstyle horizontalalign="left" />
        <itemstyle horizontalalign="left" />
    </asp:templatefield>
```

and the Java Script as below which prevents the disabled checkboxes to be checked:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   function CheckAllPaid(objRef) {

      var GridView = objRef.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
      var inputList = GridView.getElementsByTagName("input");
      for (var i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
         var row = inputList[i].parentNode.parentNode;


         if (objRef.checked && !inputList[i].disabled) {
            inputList[i].checked = true;
         } else {
            inputList[i].checked = false;
         }
      }
   }

</script>
```

Please update with Java Script only as I don't know how to use JQuery for the select all checkbox, also I am very week in Java Scripting.

Comment: Can you add a class to those checkboxes that you want to get selected?...something  like `CssClass="myClass" ` ?

Comment: Yes I can add CssClass

Comment: Ok then, I am going to post an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select checkboxes in a single column by CSS class name.

Only issue is checkbox rendered by ASP.Net is not simple ***input*** tag instead it is inside ***span*** tag, and CSS class name is applied to span tag.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRowPaid" runat="server" 
                    Enabled='<%# Eval("Amount_Paid_By_Driver").ToString() != "1" %>' 
                    CssClass="paid" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="SelectAllPaid" runat="server" 
                     onclick="CheckAllPaid(this);" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="left" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="left" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function CheckAllPaid(objRef) {
        var GridView = objRef.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
        var spanList = GridView.getElementsByClassName("paid");
        for (var i = 0; i < spanList.length; i++) {
            var input = spanList[i].childNodes[0];
            if (objRef.checked && !input.disabled) {
                input.checked = true;
            }
            else {
                input.checked = false;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I am really grateful for your answer, it's almost a week where I am trying many different methods.

Comment: I strongly suggest you to learn jQuery; basic usage is not hard to learn.  If you use jQuery, you could achieve the same result in a couple of line of codes.

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to difference the controls that you want to get `checked` from those who you don't want to get `checked`. In order to accomplish this task, we are going to use `CssClass`, like this:

```
 <asp:CheckBox ID="SelectAllPaid" runat="server" onclick="CheckAllPaid(this);" CssClass="checkThis" />
```

***JavaScript Code:***

```
function SelectAll(objRef) {
    var GridView = objRef.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    var inputList = GridView.getElementsByClassName("checkThis"); //new selector
    for (var i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
        var row = inputList[i].parentNode.parentNode;
        if (objRef.checked && !inputList[i].disabled) {
            inputList[i].checked = true;
        }
        else {
            inputList[i].checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Man, it really helped and by using the code for Win it worked like a charm.